# How to get alerted when someone views a Youtube video

Tags: youtube, video, notifications

I have a Youtube account with several videos. I often like to refresh the video page to see if the view count on any of my videos have gone up. Is there a way to automatically be alerted when someone views one of my videos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your views are not updated in real time so there is no way to know exactly when somebody actually seen your video. As for notifications I don't think that there is a way (at least not directly from YouTube) because it would be quite annoying to receive notifications for viral videos.